# Need customized output filename using awk command

Tags: awk

How to split file via `awk` command and customize the name of the output file?

I have tried,

```
awk -v RS=$val '{ outfile = "'$filename'""." NR "'.${extension}'"; print > outfile}' $file
```

Comment: Example:
Output of the filename should be fileName001, fileName002,fileName003....fileName999.


I have tried customizing it. However cannot find any command.
Current Output:
fileName1,fileName2, fileName3......fileName4

Required Output:
fileName001, fileName002, file003....... fileName999

Comment: Don't add a comment under your own question - just edit your question if you had something to add. Also include sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to create the filenames as

```
outputfile = sprintf ("filename%03d.txt", NR);
```

---

Some things to be noted in your script,

- You cannot access shell variables directly in your `awk` script, you need to create `awk` variables using `-v` formate.

  So the script should be like

  ```
    awk -v filename=$filename -v extension=$extension '{ outputfile = sprintf (filename"%03d"extension, NR); print > outputfile }'
  ```
- `awk` doesn't have any specific [concatenation operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html), just writing 2 strings together concatenates them.

Comment: I tried it but I am getting a syntax error. Please include RS=$val this as well in the command since it is the factor on which the files are getting split

Comment: @RaghvendraNayak This is just an example of how the script can be modified. You can add anymore logic to make it work for you requirement. Hope it helps :)